# Choosing return type of collection: Is there a way to return the same type that is provided?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable, type-inference

I'm in a dilemma to choose the return type of collections when writing generic extension methods for an API. I have read discussions on SO on what collection type to return and what should be the design choices. I generally prefer to accept the most basic type as argument and return the richest type.

I'm now thinking of *returning the same type that is provided with.* Irrespective of whether this is a good choice or not, is there a way this can be accomplished in an easy to use manner?

For eg. lets I have this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Generize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
                                         where T : new()
 {
     var lst = source.ToList();
     lst.Add(new T());
     return lst.AsEnumerable(); //since return type is IEnumerable.
 }
```

Now I want to return an `IEnumerable`, `ICollection` or `IList` depending on the argument `source`. So I modified this a bit.

```
 public static S Generize<S, T>(this S source) where S : IEnumerable<T>
                                               where T : new()
 {
     var lst = source.ToList();
     lst.Add(new T());
     return (S)lst.AsEnumerable(); //not sure if this works
 }
```

The main problem I'm facing is I can't get to call the function `Generize`.

```
var d = new List<int> { 23, 23 };

d.Generize(); //can not find definition and no extension method by the name.....

d.Generize<List<int>, int>(); //works but so ugly..
```

1. As Marc points out the casting doesn't work everywhere. Is there a better way to return a collection of type `S` from a `List<T>` if `S` is anyway a `IEnumerable<T>` ?
2. Can it be done without specifying types such that types are inferred automatically?
3. Also why is `d.Generize()` giving `definition not found` error rather than `types cannot be inferred` error?

**Edit:**

Though `IEnumberable<T>` can be of any concrete type, in my case it would have been only the normally found ones like `T[]` or `List<T>` or few more from `Linq` namsespace. Handling them all wont be easy. Just pointing out that the original question doesn't make sense to me now. Thanks all..!

Comment: The "works but so ugly" is only working by accident; if you tried it with an array or a `Collection<T>`, it would error

Comment: @MarcGravell let me see to it. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not getting you. I tried with `int[]` and `ICollection<T>` and it works..

Comment: if `S` is `int[]`, you get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Int32[]'.". If `S` is `Collection<int>`, you get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Int32]'.". Basically, the code you've marked with "not sure if this works": doesn't.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the semantics of this method are supposed to be. Is this a simplified example?

Comment: @MarcGravell sure run time exception is there, I was aware. I thought you were pointing to compile time error. I get it.

Comment: @AakashM Yes it is. It doesn't do a lot of complicated stuffs either, but little more than what i posted. The question is how do I return the type that it is provided with.

Comment: @nawfal: I'm not sure if I get it, but cannot you use `.AsEnumerable<T>()` extension method ? (unless it's general howto question)

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko that returns an IEnumerable of type T right? What if the argument I'm passing is ICollection<T> ? I need an ICollection<T> back then

Comment: @nawfal Could you please explain why do you want to do this? I can't figure out the purpose of `Generize`...

Comment: @PaulMichalik it is just a simple function which does examines the values in it, checks for some condition, if met does somethings like Add items to it etc. As for why I want to do this is explained in first para of my question. I'm thinking of returning the exact same type as passed without enriching any further. Like for example, if an IEnumerable int[] is passed I would like to return int[] back. If its an IList List<T> then I want to return List<T> back, etc..

Comment: Hmm I realise my question is partly foolish as `IEnumerable<T>` can be of any flavour including custom types. I will try to post an answer myself that deals with reflection, just for the sake of answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Warning: Ok my question hasn't been great, and my thinking a bit foolish. This is just to answer my post and I don't recommend it. I will rely on returning a proper `List<T>` in production code.

One way is to handle a few known types of collection classes

```
public static S Generize<S, T>(this S source, T dummyVariable) 
                              where S : class, IEnumerable<T>
{
    var lst = source.ToList();
    lst.Add(dummyVariable);

    if (source is T[])
        return lst.ToArray() as S;

    if (source is List<T>)
        return lst as S;

    if (source is Collection<T>)
        return new Collection<T>(lst) as S;

    throw new TypeAccessException();
}
```

To be bit more general, I will use some reflection..

```
public static S Generize<S, T>(this S source, T dummyVariable) 
                              where S : class, IEnumerable<T>
{
    var lst = source.ToList();
    lst.Add(dummyVariable);

    if (source is Array)
        return lst.ToArray() as S;

    foreach (var c in typeof(S).GetConstructors())
    {
        var p = c.GetParameters();

        if (p.Length != 1)
            continue;

        if (typeof(IEnumerable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(p[0].ParameterType))
            return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(S), lst) as S;
    }

    throw new TypeAccessException();
}
```

[Question 2 has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362267/cannot-find-definition-though-intellisense-lists-it) and question 3 remains a mystery.