# Cannot find definition though intellisense lists it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, type-inference

I'm getting a strange error with Visual Studio 10 (and now 11 as well). I have an extension method

```
public static S Foo<S, T>(this S s) where S : IEnumerable<T>
{
    return s;
}
```

Now if I call

```
"".Foo(); // => 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Foo' and no extension method 'Foo' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm not at all understanding what's happening under hood. The annoying part is that the **intellisense lists `Foo` for `IEnumberable<T>`s**. At best it should have given a `type can't be inferred error`.

If I call it this way:

```
Extension.Foo(""); // => The type arguments for method 'Extension.Foo<S,T>(S)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

**Why cannot type be inferred in the above case?**

**More:**

Suppose I have:

```
public static S Foo<S, T>(this S s, T t) where S : IEnumerable<T>
{
    return s;
}
```

And if I call:

```
"".Foo(1);
```

The type inference is so smart here to tell me that *`Foo` should be returning `IEnumerable<int>` and `string` is not all that!!*

So if compiler can know `Foo` is expecting a char as the first argument, then why doesn't my first example just compile? **In other words why is that in the first example the compiler know `T` in that case is char?**

As expectedly this works for the second example:

```
"".Foo('l');
```

I'm just wondering why can't `T` be inferred as `char` in first example, after all string is `IEnumberable<char>`.

---

## Edit:

I got the answer from SLaks. But it's so strange that C# doesn't do this (kind of type inference) considering compiler takes into account the generic constraints as well when exposing the available methods to operate on an object.

In other words:

```
public static S Foo<S, T>(this S s)
{
    return s;
}
```

makes `Foo` available on all `object`s.

```
public static S Foo<S, T>(this S s) where S : IEnumerable<T>
{
    return s;
}
```

makes `Foo` available on all `IEnumerable<T>`s since **it knows** `S` is `IEnumerable<T>`. So I was thinking C# will be even inferring the type of `T`! Thanks everyone! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type inference engine isn't smart enough to do that.

C# type inference only looks at the method *signature*.
[Generic constraints are not part of the signature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx).

Since `T` is not used directly in the signature, the compiler will not infer it.

Comment: Specifically setting the generic types would work though: `"".Foo<string,char>();`

Comment: @RenéWolferink that's obvious, my question was about why not inferring type automatically.

Comment: Which is why I added it as a comment, not as an answer, just for completeness. ;)

Comment: Slakhs though I understood your reasoning, the link you posted is not the right one. It talks about overload resolution and not type inference. Kindly edit the answer.

Comment: @nawfal: It's still true, and I don't know off-hand of a better link.